# how are these XML comments generated in C# code behind automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I look at the code-behind, I see a lot of `///` xml comments for every property and class name, but how are these comments generated?

Automatically? Via 3rd party?  I don't think my ex-colleauge was typing `///` for every property and class....

What's the automatic way (tool/short key/whatever) of generation?

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of items from the repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the single entity from the repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Id of the entity</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    TEntity Get(Int32 id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an entity to the repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    TEntity Add(TEntity entity);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an entity in the repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Int32 Update(TEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your best option would be to ask your ex-colleague. GhostDoc perhaps?

Comment: It certainly looks like GhostDoc to me. It does try to work out comments itself but is hit and miss. I let ghost doc generate the comments and then If they need expanding on or do not make sense I modify them myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GhostDoc](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/46A20578-F0D5-4B1E-B55D-F001A6345748) will be helpful for you to generate XmlComment automatically.

If you want to to it manually then when you type / 3 times (`///`) above any property, method, constructor, class  or interface then related comment automatically generated with empty summary, parameter and return values and you have to write your own definitions/descriptions about your implementations. These comments are used for Intellisense

**How It works:**

If I have following constructor with XML Comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// The constructor sets the name, age and cash
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The name of the guy</param>
/// <param name="cash">The amount of cash the guy starts with</param>
public Guy(string name, int age, int cash) {
     //This is constructor implementation with XML Comments
}
```

Then when you initialize or use this constructor then intellisense will show this XML comment as below image

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you type `/` thrice on the line above any property/class/method declaration inside Visual Studio, it'll generate these snippets.

They are used by intellisense and by other third party tools to generate documentation for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which could auto generate xml comments for you.

> GhostDoc is a Visual Studio extension that automatically generates XML
>   documentation comments for methods and properties based on their type,
>   parameters, name, and other contextual information.

Answer (score 0):

When you type in `///` above a method / class / property in visual studio it will auto generate a structure including items such as the parameters and the return value for that item if applicable. This is detailed further in this MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkxs89c5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).